# how to add dynamically for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

i want to show all combinations of distinct objects into distinct bins. n is bin id k is object id.
i can do it with static size of loops like:

```
combination= []

k = 6

n = 3

        

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for l in range(n):
            for h in range(n):
                for t in range(n):
                    for y in range(n):
                        combination.append([i,j,l,h,t,y])
                    
print(combination)
```

output is:

> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],  [0, 0,
> 0, 0, 1, 0],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],  [0, 0, 0, 0,
> 2, 0],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]...

There are as many for loops as k values. How can I dynamically increase - decrease for loop based on k value?

Thanks for advices!

Comment: take a look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (combinatoric iterators section) module (it is built-in)

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, of if you have special conditions to prune combinations, use recursion (think: each element from current list, combined with all combinations of other lists), otherwise use `itertools.product` (not `combinations`)

Comment: Sometimes memory error can occur because of itertools. So I looked for a different way. 
But Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

k = 4
n = 2

for p in product(range(n), repeat=k):
    print(p)

(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 0)
# ...
```

Or, in order to get them as a list of lists:

```
product = [*map(list, product(range(n), repeat=k))]
```

If you want to implement it by hand, use recursion. Here is a sample generator function:

```
def prod(n, k):
    if k:
        for p in prod(n, k-1):
            for i in range(n):
                yield p + [i]
    else:
        yield []

>>> list(prod(2, 3))
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], 
 [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], 
 [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: it would be better for me if i don't use any module at the moment. Thank you for your concern. the solution you suggested also solves the problem

Comment: Added a plain python implementation. No imports needed.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you should probably use `itertools.product` for this, as shown in the other answer. However, those methods do not always fit exactly what you need. In this case, the "dynamic number of loops" problem can usually be solved with recursion. In this case, you can try something like this:

```
def combine(lst, count):
    if count <= 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        res = []
        for comb in combine(lst, count-1):
            for x in lst:
                res.append([x, *comb])
        return res
```

Or as a generator, i.e. producing combinations as needed and not all at once:

```
def combine(lst, count):
    if count <= 0:
        yield []
    else:
        yield from ([x, *comb] for comb in combine(lst, count-1) for x in lst)
```

Implementing those methods yourself can also be faster if e.g. you are only interested in combinations whose sum is lower than some value or similar, as this allows you to prune entire branches of the search space instead of generating all combinations and filtering afterwards.

Comment: That's really what i looking for. Thank you. Sometimes i can't imagine what should i do. you helped a lot.